# Why form is non-editable on offline page?

Tags: fix-my-code, css, gantry

This is probably not directly a J! problem so if you vote for closing, I'll remove the question.

**Joomla 3.3.6 Offline page** – there is a login form displayed, but it is not editable, although its HTML looks fine. Even cursor remains in arrow shape over input boxes, it is not changed into `I`. Nothing can be typed into text boxes and blue button doesn't respond. I thought it is a browser issue but I can see the same in multiple browsers.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It's being caused by the overlapping background being applied to the parent element:

```
.rt-footer-surround-pattern:before {
    background: url("../images/patterns/noise.png") repeat;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

## Update with solution:

Add the following CSS:

```
#rt-subscription-form {
    background: #12374d url("../images/patterns/noise.png") repeat;
}
#rt-authorized-form {
    background: #35363a url("../images/patterns/noise.png") repeat;
}
```

and remove the CSS code I showed that was causing the problem at the top of my question.

Hope this helps

Comment: @miroxlav - See my update. I can fix it by removing the background but am trying to fix it so that you get to keep this background overlay

Comment: @miroxlav - Updated my answer again with a working solution ;)

Comment: wow. thanks. Now I understand the overlapping layer issue. I can't understand very well that such an easy-to-spot bug leaked into a commercial template.

Comment: True, quite surprising they didn't notice it. If you still have your subscription on Rockettheme, I would highly suggest telling them just in case it's an issue with other templates ;)

Comment: Finally this problem was addressed by template upgrade which I did not notice. My bad. Sorry for keeping you busy. See [the second answer](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5010/324) for solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Template upgrade helped**
without need of manually changing any code:

After some research I found the problem was named in template change log. You can see it in [the change log](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/templates/anacron/modal/changelog) for version 1.2 (scroll down the page). Then reset of Gantry cache needs to be performed and problem gets corrected.